# What's the difference between 'feed forward network' and 'fully-connected network'?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Sometimes I'm confused with these two terms. So, I ask to clarify this.
Someone says 'feed forward network' is a typical neural network.
If then, 'feed forward network' means bigger scope including 'fully-connected network'?
If then, RNN or CNN is included in 'feed forward network' also?
I guess it's not..
I hope to have a clear description. Thank you.

Comment: Questions regarding pure machine learning (including deep learning) concepts should be asked on [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are independent properties really:

- A feed forward network is a network with no recurrent connections, that is, it is the opposite of a recurrent network (RNN). It is an important distinction because in a feed forward network the gradient is clearly defined and computable through [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) (i.e. chain rule), whereas in a recurrent network the gradient computation requires, potentially, an infinite number of operations, so you usually have to limit it to a fixed number of steps, and it is also more expensive in any case (see [backpropagation through time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time)).
- A fully-connected network, or maybe more appropriately a fully-connected layer in a network is one such that every input neuron is connected to every neuron in the next layer. This, for example, contrasts with convolutional layers, where each output neuron depends on a subset of the input neurons.

A classic [multilayer perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron) is a feed forward network composed of fully connected layers. Most so-called "convolutional networks" are also feed forward and are composed of a number of convolutional and pooling layers, but also some fully connected layers. Recurrent units like [LSTMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) are probably not generally regarded as fully connected, since its internal architecture is a bit more complex and specific, but you could say they somewhat are, though, since every output is, in the end, dependant on every input to some extent; however, they are not feed forward, since they present recurrent connections.

Answer (score 1):

A feedforward network is a network without a cycle, reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network

CNN is feedforward network, RNN is not. Actually RNN does not have cycle either, just from certain perspective you can imagine that RNN has a cycle for understanding the concept.

Some state of the art network contains both convolution layers and fully-connected layers, in the full-connected layers, neurons have connections to all neurons in pervious layer. In convolution layers, each neuron only connects to a few neurons (depends on kernel size) in previous layer.